# Error while importing the pywinauto module

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I'm using python(3.8)when I installed the pywinauto(0.6.8) module it got successfully installed and now whenever I am trying to import the module it showing me several errors:
I have tried to install this module on python 3.7 and facing same issue.

problem in pywinauto - TypeError: item 2 in *argtypes* passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
[image: problem in pywinauto - TypeError: item 2 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.]

Answer (score 1):

This is bug in Python 3.8.1 and 3.7.6. Downgrade to earlier Python version.

Python 3.8.2 will revert the wrong code.